# iTextSharp: table row gets pushed to new page if it doesn't fit on the current one

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, page-break

I'm using `iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(TextReader reader, StyleSheet style)` to convert an html table into a pdf doc. Some rows contain a lot of data, and may not fit on the current page, so iTextSharp creates a new page and places the row there. If the row doesn't fit on the next page, it splits it correctly.

Is there a way to tell it to not use these page breaks? Here is what it looks like:

[image: Row gets dropped to the next page by iTextSharp]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick that worked for me is to inspect the results of `ParseToList()` and look for any elements that are of type `PdfPTable`. If you see one set its `SplitLate` property to `False`. Here's some VB that you should be able to convert to C# fairly easily:

```
Dim Elements = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(SR, Nothing)
For Each El In Elements
    If TypeOf El Is PdfPTable Then
        DirectCast(El, PdfPTable).SplitLate = False
    End If
    Doc.Add(El)
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

Chris Haas answer is great - it worked for me.
Here is one in C#:

```
        string template = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\my_template.html");
        var htmlText = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), model: GetViewModel());

        TextReader reader = new StringReader(htmlText);
        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 30, 30);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);

            document.Open();
            var pages = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(reader, new StyleSheet());
            foreach (var page in pages)
            {
                if (page is PdfPTable)
                {
                    (page as PdfPTable).SplitLate = false;
                }
                document.Add(page as IElement);
            }

            document.Close();

            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\my_template.pdf", stream.ToArray());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure table rows are "atomic", and will be CROPPED if they overflow a given page.

Does the PDF from the above image continue that row on the next page?